# NSFetchedResultsController: sort descriptors and sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a core data model like so...

```
[Country] <--->> [League] <--->> [Match]
```

And I'm using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to display the `Matches` into a `UITableView`.

I've done this a million times before but for some reason the sections are going wrong and I can't work out why.

I have created the sort descriptors like so...

```
NSSortDescriptor *countrySD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"league.country.name" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *leagueSD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"league.name" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *dateSD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[countrySD, leagueSD, dateSD];
```

First I want to check I have put these in the correct order. This should first sort by the `country.name` then sort by the `league.name` and then sort by the `startDate`.

i.e.

1. Anything in `Albania` should come before anything in `Spain`.
2. In a single country, anything in `League 1` should come before anything in `League 2`.
3. In a single league all the matches should be displayed in `startDate` order with the earliest first.

Then I'm creating the `NSFRC` with this...

```
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.moc sectionNameKeyPath:@"league.leagueID" cacheName:nil];
```

So this should group the table by matches with different `league.leagueID` values.

It should be something like...

```
Albania - League 1
    12:00
    13:00
Albania - League 2
    09:00
    14:00
France - League 1
    09:00
Spain - A League
    08:00
    12:00
Spain - B League
    09:00
```

It isn't working though. I get multiple headers for the same league. Some of the matches appear under the wrong header etc...

I've checked the values (NSLogged) of the matches appearing under the wrong league and they actually have the correct league. So even though they have `Spain - A League` they are appearing under `France - League A` (for example).

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key path used as `sectionNameKeyPath` argument must be the same key used
in the first sort descriptor (or generate the same relative ordering).

There is (as far as I know) no way to use two or more sort descriptors for grouping
the results of a fetched results controller into sections.

Comment: Thanks. Going to have to resort to doing it with fetch requests and setting up a context watcher of my own :(

Comment: @Fogmeister: Alternatively, you could add an additional attribute that holds `<country>.<league>` and use that as section key and first sort descriptor.

Comment: Ooh, that sounds like a plan. Would I put that in the League class?

Comment: YES! YES! YES! Thanks! Works perfectly! Wish I could give you another +1.

Comment: You rock! I've been hunting for what was wrong with my app for 4 hours, and this was it.