# NSFetchedResultsController for sectioned fetching?

Tags: ios, core-data

I need to fetch entries for an entity and sort them by sections like how you would do for a tableView. However, I'm doing this just to count the number of occurrences for each section, I don't need the actual data associated with each entry. My end goal is to have a dictionary of format:

`[String : Int] // Key: Section identifier, Value: occurrences for that section`

Is using an `NSFetchedResultsController` overkill for such a task or should I do a normal `NSFetchRequest` and section off the data after it's fetched?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSFetchedResultsController: sort descriptors and sections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280452/nsfetchedresultscontroller-sort-descriptors-and-sections)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `NSFetchedResultsController` results in one fetch and a call on the value of the `sectionKeyPath` for every item in your list (which will fault every item, and possibly run code if you have a custom property for the `sectionKeyPath`).

If you can use `countForFetchRequest` and make a separate fetch request for each section, it would result in a fetch request for every section and no faulting.

If you have many sections with very few items in them then using a fetchedResultsController will likely be faster.  If you have very few sections with many items in them then the second method would likely be faster.  The only way to really know which way is faster it test and benchmark.

I think that either way is fine unless you are experiencing performance issues and you should do what make the most sense for you code.  Personally I would use a `NSFetchedResultsController`.  It is my preferred way to display data, as it can also help keep your data in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a fetch request specifying the section identifier as `propertiesToGroupBy` and using an `NSExpression` to calculate the count of the items.  The fetch request will need to have `resultType` set to `.DictionaryResultType`, and the fetch will return an array of dictionaries.  Each dictionary will have two keys/values, one being the section identifier, the other being the item count.  There are plenty of examples on SO if you search on "GROUP BY" and "COUNT", but I can put some code together if you provide details of your entities, attributes, section identifiers, etc.  As indicated in the other answer, it is difficult to tell whether this will provide any significant speed advantages over the FRC or normal fetch.